# Error in expression string-join: expected ")", found ","

Tags: xml, xslt

I am fairly new to XSLT. I am attempting to make a function that strips any dashes(aka "-") from a string, then returns the string with a dash after the first two characters, followed by the remaining 7 characters.

My XSL looks like this:

```
<fn:function name="nx:DashedResult">
    <xsl:param name="String"/>
    <fn:result select="fn:string-join((substring(translate($String,'-',''),1,2),substring(translate($String,'-',''),3,9)),'-')"/>
</fn:function>
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Error in expression fn:string-join((substring(translate($String,'-',''),1,2),substring(translate($String,'-',''),3,9)),'-'): expected ")", found ","
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to add a closing `)` in `string-join((substring(translate($String,'-',''),1,2),substring(translate($String,'-',''),3,9))),'-')`. But XSLT does not have an `fn:result` element and the `fn` namespace is not the one used for the XSLT elements anyway.

Answer (score 0):

So if I'm right in thinking, given an input of `abc-def-ghij-kl` you want the output `ab-cdefghi`

If so try:

```
concat(substring(translate($string, '-', ''),1,2), '-', substring(translate($string, '-', ''),3,7))
```

This adds the first 2 dash stripped characters, followed by dash, followed by the preceding 7 dash stripped characters.